# Append Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have the following problem. I want to extend a numpy array in a loop, so that each array is seperated from the next like `a=[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]],b=[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]-->[[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]],[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]]`

My approach so far:

```
count=0
for i in range(int(max(allCoo[:,4]))+1):

        mask1 = allCoo[:,4] == count 
        if count>0:
            trackList=np.vstack((trackList,np.array((allCoo[mask1]))))
        else:
            trackList=np.array((allCoo[mask1]))

        count+=1
```

But this just give me things like: `[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]`

Best regards

Comment: Collect the arrays in a list, or list of lists, and do the `stack/concatenate` once at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `dstack` instead of `vstack` if you want a new dimension

```
p.dstack([a,b]).swapaxes(1,2)

array([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])

np.vstack([a,b])

array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Nice thank you. But what is for arrays with different array dumensions like np.dstack(([[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]],[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]])).swapaxes(1,2). Here i get the error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: That output would be a ragged array (since the second dimension would not be fixed) and thus wouldn't be a valid `numpy` array.  You'd be better off making a list of arrays then.

Comment: `np.stack` is a newer function with more flexibility in adding that new dimension.